# Why preg_match returns some empty elements?

Tags: php, regex

I've written the regexp `^(?:([1-5])|([1-5]) .*|.* ([1-5])|.* ([1-5]) .*)$` to match either standalone digit 1-5, or a digit separated by at least one space form the rest of the string. I've tested it in online services and the result is the digit itself. However, when using code

```
preg_match('/^(?:([1-5])|([1-5]) .*|.* ([1-5])|.* ([1-5]) .*)$/', 'order 12314124 5', $matches);
```

I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => order 12314124 5 [1] => [2] => [3] => 5 )
```

The [0] element is a full match which is good. I anticipated the [1] element be 5 but it's empty, and there's another empty element. Why these empty elements appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used the regex at regex101.com, all non-participating (i.e. those that did not match) groups are hidden. You can turn them on in options:

[image]

And you will see them:

[image]

A quick fix is to use a branch reset `(?|...)` instead of a non-capturing group `(?:...)` and access the `$matches[1]` value:

```
preg_match('/^(?|([1-5])|([1-5]) .*|.* ([1-5])|.* ([1-5]) .*)$/', 'order 12314124 5', $matches);
print_r($matches[1]); // => 5
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ovEDCd)